# i am unable to run gimp on Ubuntu 16.04 lts,how can i solve this?

Tags: gimp

I tried to install GIMP 2.9, using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get install gimp,
```

Now if try to run GIMP I get this error:

[image]

Comment: GIMP is available in the official repositories. Any special reason for using that PPA?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade *all* packages coming from the newly set up PPA.